# get records from table starting from row 5 onwards

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql Database and I want to get the records starting from row 5 onwards. This is what i am sing right now

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 
limit 5 18446744073709551615 ORDER BY sortOrder ASC
```

But it is throwing me an error

Error Executing Database Query.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18446744073709551615 

 ORDER BY 

 sortOrder ' at line 6
```

Also i am not sure at this point if this is the correct way of doing it or not

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You require OFFSET

Example:

```
SELECT something FROM table LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset;

//or alternatively
SELECT something FROM table LIMIT $offset,$limit;
```

Regarding your error:

Remove the number - what is it for in the first place?

Your statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 
OFFSET 5 ORDER BY sortOrder ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma `,` in your sql query.. just change it to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 
limit 5, 18446744073709551615 ORDER BY sortOrder ASC
       ↑
```

Explanation: `LIMIT` with two arguments (**comma separated**) will take first argument as `OFFSET` and second as the maximum number of rows to return.

Alternatively, if you just want to get all rows from a particular record.. you can use `OFFSET` keyword. The following will fetch rows starting from 5th row.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1
OFFSET 5 ORDER BY sortOrder ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You need to just Rearrange the sequence of Instruction.
Make Sure 'sortOrder' column exists in your Categories table.

The Following Query should work,

```
    Select  * from Categories Where status =1
    ORDER BY sortOrder ASC
    Limit 4, 999980090909
```

If you want to get the rows starting from 5 , then  your Limit value should start from 4 and the second value can be some larger number.
Hope this helps you!